# Why does the TwoWay binding in my UserControl work only OneWay?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a very simple toggle-style UserControl. Just a circle in a rectangle:

```
    <Grid MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Rectangle x:Name="Body" Width="100" Height="50"  RadiusY="25" RadiusX="25" Fill="DarkGray"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="Nipple" Width="46" Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="DimGray" Margin="-50,0,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
```

...that has a single DependencyProperty "IsOnProperty"

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOnProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsOn", typeof(bool), typeof(MyToggleSwitch),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    
    public bool IsOn
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOnProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsOnProperty, value);
            if (value)
            {
                Nipple.Margin = Offset_Right;
            }
            else
            {
                Nipple.Margin = Offset_Left;
            }
        }
    }
```

In my MainWindow I have a single property "IsOn"...

```
bool _ison;
public bool IsOn
{ 
    get
    {
        return _ison;
    }
    set
    {
        _ison = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsOn");
    }
}
```

...and I can databind my DependencyProperty to that value:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyToggleSwitch x:Name="Toggle" IsOn="{Binding IsOn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Now I can happily click on the control and watch in amazement how the "nipple" flips and how the underlying DependecyProperty changes back and forth. Awesome!

Here's where it gets strange:
In my UserControl I have made the databinding TwoWay...

```
IsOn="{Binding IsOn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

...but if the underlying bool changes from elsewhere in the code, it does not propagate that change back up to my UserControl.

Is something wrong with my DependencyProperty?

Comment: Your dependency property declaration is incorrect. There must not be anything else than the SetValue call in the setter of the property wrapper. In order to react on property value changes, register a PropertyChangedCallback with the property metadata.

Comment: And since you have already registered the property with BindsTwoWayByDefault, this is sufficient: `IsOn="{Binding IsOn}"`. Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` would only be required if you had registered a different default UpdateSourceTrigger.

Comment: An alternative to a PropertyChangedCallback that set the Ellipse's Margin in code behind would be a Style with a DataTrigger on the control's IsOn property.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially for mentining how to react to changing values. I saw those other questions, but was unable to recognise them as "my issue". THANKS!